# how can i user the regular expression to check if the string is the scientific notation or not?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

i would like to check user input which is i will get as string and pass it to an array ! now i would like to use the regular expression to see if the number is the scientific notation or not ! also i would like to do the same thing for octal as well!!! 
i have my work here for floating point and it's working perfect but for the scientific notation and octal not actually working don't know why !! 
also  can i  use the pattern compile too ! if yeah how !!

thanks for help 
here is the work for the checking the floating point

```
private static boolean floating(String [] data) {
    int count =0;
    boolean correct = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        if (str.matches("((-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)+")){
            System.out.println(" it's a floating number ");
            correct= true;
            break;
         }else 
             correct = false;

    }if (correct ==true){
        return true;
    }else 
    return false; 

}
```

here is my method and expression for the scientific notation .

```
    private void SNotation(String [] data) {
        int count =0;
    boolean correct = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        if (str.matches('(?<![\d.])(?!\.\.)(?<![\d.][eE][+-])(?<![\d.][eE])(?<!\d[.,])'){ 
/// here is not accepting the expression which i believe is right !! 
            System.out.println(" it's a floating number ");
            correct= true;
            break;
         }else 
             correct = false;

    }if (correct ==true){
        return true;
    }else 
    return false; 

for pattern compile i found these rules but dont know how should i use it !
```

> Decimal: (0|[-+]?[1-9][0-9]*) Floating number: [-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$
>   Scientific notation: [-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]?[eE][-+]?[0-9]+$ Octal:
>   0[0-7]*

Answer (score 0):

You could use just one regex for them all. Each capture group matches a different
type.

`"^(?:([+-]?(?:\\d+\\.\\d*|\\.\\d+))|(\\\\[0-7]+)|([+-]?\\d+)|([+-]?(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+)[eE][+-]?\\d+))$"`

Formatted

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      (                             # (1 start), Float
           [+-]? 
           (?:
                \d+ \. \d* 
             |  \. \d+ 
           )
      )                             # (1 end)
   |  
      ( \\ [0-7]+ )                 # (2), Octal
   |  
      (                             # (3 start), Integer
           [+-]? 
           \d+ 
      )                             # (3 end)
   |  
      (                             # (4 start), Scientific Notation
           [+-]? 
           (?:
                \d+ 
                (?: \. \d* )?
             |  \. \d+ 
           )
           [eE] [+-]? \d+ 
      )                             # (4 end)
 )
 $
```